# understanding transfer learning for mobileNet

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, logistic, convolution, transfer-learning

I am trying to visualise how transfer learning (feature extraction in particular) works with mobileNet using ml5.js.

With ml5.js, you can extract a part of the pre-trained model (the features). Those features allow you to 'retrain' or 'reuse' the model for a new custom task (transfer learning). Then, we can map the features to our own set of labels. There's a good explanation here: https://youtu.be/kRpZ5OqUY6Y

I tried to visualise the process according to the video above.

[image]

However, this figure looks like we're not doing any training at all and just mapping the whole thing to our custom labels. What could be a good way to visualise the feature extraction process with mobile net?

ml5 featureExtraction documentation: https://learn.ml5js.org/#/reference/feature-extractor

[image]

Comment: You have to learn the new mapping still.

Comment: From the documentation I understand that we use the "features" to retrain. However, the video explains it as if we are just mapping the logits to our own labels. Then where is the training/learning happening considering that the mobileNet architecture itself is shown before the "feature extraction" part? The problem is that I am not understanding it well enough to make a visualization. @AryaMcCarthy

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy did you mean something like the edited picture that I added now?

Comment: Yes, that picture is what I meant.